# Dot notation to arrays

Tags: arrays, ruby

I got a string `'tileBlock.tag.title'` and an Hash like this:

```
{
  "title"=>"headline",
  "body"=>"body text",
  "link"=>"#",
  "tileBlock"=>{"title"=>"Home", "tag"=>{"title"=>"home", "id"=>45}, "active"=>true}
}
```

Is there a way to transform `'tileBlock.tag.title'` to something like `'object[:tileBlock][:tag][:title]`?

Comment: Not clear what you mean. Is `'object[:tileBlock][:tag][:title]` [sic] an object?

Comment: What role is that object playing? And what is `object`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `Enumerable#inject`, take `str="tileBlock.tag.title"`.

```
str.split(".").inject(object) { |m, x| m[x] }
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `dig()` method of Hash in order to retrieve your value. You just need to transform your string into an array of keys :

```
#Init values
my_string = 'tileBlock.tag.title'
my_hash = {
  "title"=>"headline",
  "body"=>"body text",
  "link"=>"#",
  "tileBlock"=>{
    "title"=>"Home", 
    "tag"=>{"title"=>"home", "id"=>45}, 
    "active"=>true
   }
}
#The code
my_keys = my_string.split('.')
# => ["tileBlock", "tag", "title"]
my_result = my_hash.dig(*my_keys)
# => "home"
```

`Hash#dig()` Documentation : http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0_preview1/Hash.html#method-i-dig

Comment: I guess .dig isn't part von ruby 2.1, isn't it? @Caillou

Comment: Indeed, dig appears in ruby-2.3

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure what `object` is, but if it is a nested hash/array, and you want to call `object[:tileBlock][:tag][:title]` using `s = 'tileBlock.tag.title'`, then,

```
object.dig(*s.split(".").map(&:to_sym))
```